# Hanging only to the first instance of the line, and deleting all further copies

Tags: vim

I have a file with some lines *(incredible, right :)* and need to clean it up. I would like to delete all but the first instance of the line. Is there a plugin for Vim that lets me select the line (visual line selection) that keeps the first instance of the line, and delets all further ones, regardless of whether I selected one of the further ones (for I may miss the first instance at the beginning of the file)?

If you have an idea of how to quickly select the line, delete every but the first instance in a file, that would work too.

All ideas on this welcomed.

Comment: Are the identical lines sequential? Are they scattered all over the file?

Comment: Do you care about the order of the lines? If not, you can do ":sort u".

Comment: @JiříPospíšil - Unfortunatelly :), the order is important.

Comment: @seliopou - Scattered all over the file, yes.

Answer (score 3):

I hope you have awk available. If true, you can do in this way:

- open your file in vim
- type (in one line)   `:command! RML exec '%!awk -vl="'.getline(".").'" ''$0==l{if(\!f)print $0;f=1;next;}1'''`

this will create a command called `RML` (Remove Line)

- then move your cursor to the line you want to remove duplicates, type `:RML<ENTER>` the duplicates are removed, and only first line stays.
- this way will keep the order of lines in your original file
- this way works no matter your repeated line are continued or not

for detail you could check out the gif screencast below:

[image]

Comment: I don't have awk available. In addition I would like to incorporate this line deletion as a part of the function, and therefore would like to depend on other programs as little as possible.

Answer (score 0):

maybe simpler without vim :

if the line that you want to keep only 1 occurence of matches the regexp "aregexp",

```
grep "$aregexp" file | head -n 1 > /tmp/thatline #first occurence of the line.
all_other_occurences="$(fgrep -n "$(cat /tmp/thatline)" file | head -n +2 | tac)"
   #fgrep string file : search string in file, literrally, without using regexp
   #head -n +2 (or on some machines: head -n +1) skips the 1st line of the input
   #tac : so that we have line numbers in reverse order (allowing to delete them without moving the next ones up!)
#here add a test to see if all_other_occurence is empty : nothing to do then (there was no lines other than the first one)
#otherwise: 
for linetodelete in "$all_other_occurence" ; do
    # either delete line n in file using sed -i,
    #    or     create&concatenate a vim command that later will be used to
    #           delete those lines from inside vim, via script or copy/paste manually...
done
```

another approach (probably faster!):  delete all lines and reinsert the 1st occurence at the right place

```
thelinenumber=$( awk '$0~var{print NR;exit}' var="$aregexp" < file)
   #will exit as soon as it finds the 1st occurence
theline="$(sed -e "${thelinenumber}p" < file)" 
fgrep -v "$theline" file > newfile #delete all occurence
awk -v l="$thelinenumber" -v s="$theline" 'NR == l {print s} {print}' file > file.new
```

I did not check those, but I hope you can see the intent and correct any syntax problem (and add double checks, for empty variables, the test if there is just 1 occurence of the line, etc)

Comment: I am still looking for a vim solution.

Answer (score 0):

a quick way is this

go to the line you want

```
ma
0y$
:g/\V<ctrl-r>"/m'a
:/\V<ctrl-r>"/d
```

Answer (score 0):

My [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602) provides a

```
:DeleteDuplicateLinesOf .
```

command (as well as other related commands) that does exactly that.