# Delete all but the first instance of a line

Tags: vim, windows-7

How to delete all but the first instance of a line, which is known?

For instance, I have

```
LOADING CONDITION :   LIGHTSHIP CONDITION
```

several of these spread out through the file's contents. I would like to keep only the first instance which is somewhere near the top.

Ideas anyone?

Comment: Haven't you asked that same question already?! Possible duplicate of [Hanging only to the first instance of the line, and deleting all further copies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236226/hanging-only-to-the-first-instance-of-the-line-and-deleting-all-further-copies)

Comment: @IngoKarkat - Yes, similar one. In the other case I was interested in deleting all but the first instances of all lines which were repeated several times. And whose contents I do not know in advance. I just wanted to have only one copy of each. In this case, I want to delete all but the first copy of a line whose contents are known to me. Also, I would like to do it without awk/grep/... since those tools are not usually available on Windows.

Comment: @IngoKarkat ha, when I saw this question, I felt that I have ever answered it sometime earlier, but not sure... you found that link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602) provides a command (and other related ones) that makes this very simple:

```
:DeleteDuplicateLinesOf /^LOADING CONDITION :   LIGHTSHIP CONDITION$/
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `:global` command combined with a range.

```
:0/LOADING CONDITION/+,$g//d
```

Explanation:

- `[range]g/{pat}/{cmd}` run a command, `{cmd}`, on every line matching `{pat}` inside the giving line range, `[range]`.
- `0/LOADING CONDITION/` starting with the first line find the pattern `LOADING CONDITION`
- `0/LOADING CONDITION/+1` start the range 1 line below the first instance
- `+1` can be shorted to just `+` because the 1 can be assumed.
- `,$` the end of the range will be the last line in the file which is refereed to as `$`
- `g//` use the last search pattern. In this case the pattern from the range
- `:delete` or `:d` for short is the ex command used to delete the lines

For more information see

```
:h :g
:h :d
:h range
```

Comment: Great explanation, and clever use of `/{pattern}/` as part of a range.

Answer (score 2):

```
gg (make cursor back to top)
/LOADING CONDITION :   LIGHTSHIP CONDITION (enter)
n
:.,$g//d
```

Comment: I ment, how do I do that "programatically"? So I can put that in a script file. I need to do this for 272 files.

Comment: it could be written in a vim function. btw, is awk/sed available there? it would do it very easily.

Comment: @ldigas just saw your comment about the awk/grep, sry.